# Duda sobre ejecución de código PHP en Aptana

Tags: php, aptana

Estoy aprendiendo PHP, y trabajando en el IDE Aptana, pero tengo un problema cuando voy a ejecutar código como "Run as" para ir testeando me sale este error

> "The current debugger does not have any defined PHP executables,
>   please define a PHP executable location"

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe? 
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes instalar un servidor local capaz de interpretar PHP, te recomiendo wamp/xamp, es un stack que incluye PHP y Mysql entre otros, enlace: [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

La instalación es muy sencilla, simplemente asegúrate que el puerto en el que pongas el servidor no tengas otro servicio escuchando. (Si no tienes instalado ningún otro servidor te funcionará con el puerto por defecto)

Una vez tengas WAMP corriendo en tu ordenador, simplemente Vas a preferencias en el IDE APtana, Busca PHP, y en Intérpretes le dices que tu intérprete de PHP se encuentra en: `/DirectorioDondeTienesWAMP/PHP/php.exe`

Comment: Si , el XAMP lo tengo ya corriendo y demás. Pero tengo que descargarme algo de la página de PHP?

Comment: No, simplemente dile al IDE Aptana donde se encuentra tu intérprete de PHP pasándole la ruta del mismo desde preferencias -> PHP -> Intérprete PHP, que será donde tengas XAMP, un directorio llamado PHP, y dentro de este un ejecutable llamado php.exe

Comment: @RoyalUp si tienes instalado XAMP ya tienes agregado PHP (deberia ser lo mas logico) por ende tienes que solo buscar la ruta de tu php

Comment: Me ha servido , ya lo he podido conectar. Gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 2):

Debes configurar en `aptana` en `Preferencias->General->PHP->PHP Interpreters`, Buscar la carpeta donde tienes `PHP` y seleccionarla para que asi ejecute tu codigo.